# Android UI stops responding

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, audio

I'm building an app for detecting audio and recording audio above a certain sound threshold.

The UI simply has one button labelled 'Listen'. When the listen button is clicked the app runs as planned detecting and recording audio (this is evident from the Android Studio monitor) and once clicked the listen button should change to "Stop" and of course when stop is clicked the app should stop running and the button should return to "Listen" ready to go again.

However once the app starts running the UI freezes and stops responding, the button stays as "Listen", clicking doesn't do anything, I'm unable to navigate to a different tab and I have to terminate the monitor in the IDE.

Any idea how to fix this? I have attached both the Java and the xml code below.

Java

```
public class ListenFragment extends Fragment implements
    ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 0;
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AcousticRecognition";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private boolean isRecording = false;
private String audioFilename = null;
private String wavFilePath = null;
private String fingerprintFilePath = null;
private String fn = null;
private Button listen;
private View mLayout;
private LogDBWrapper logDB;
private FingerprintDBWrapper fingerprintDB;
private WaveDBWrapper wavDB;
private Thread detectThread = null;

/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public ListenFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen, container, false);


    mLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.record_layout);
    listen = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.listen);
    fingerprintDB = new FingerprintDBWrapper(getActivity());
    logDB = new LogDBWrapper(getActivity());
    wavDB = new WaveDBWrapper(getActivity());

    //set buffer size
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    detectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            record();
        }
    });

    //event handlers for record button
    listen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isRecording) {
                listen.setText(R.string.stop);
                isRecording = true;
                detectThread.run();
            } else {
                detectThread.interrupt();
                stopRecording();
                listen.setText(R.string.listen);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void audioDetect() {
    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
            bufferSize
    );
    // Start Recording.
    recorder.startRecording();

    int numberOfReadBytes = 0;
    byte audioBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    boolean recording = false;
    float tempFloatBuffer[] = new float[3];
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int totalReadBytes = 0;
    byte totalByteBuffer[] = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];



    // While data come from microphone.
    while (true) {
        float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
        short sample = 0;

        numberOfReadBytes = recorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

        // Analyze Sound.
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += 2) {
            sample = (short) ((audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8);
            totalAbsValue += (float) Math.abs(sample) / ((float) numberOfReadBytes / (float) 2);
        }

        // Analyze temp buffer.
        tempFloatBuffer[tempIndex % 3] = totalAbsValue;
        float temp = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            temp += tempFloatBuffer[i];

        if ((temp >= 0 && temp <= 350) && !recording) {
            Log.i("TAG", "1");
            tempIndex++;
            continue;
        }

        if (temp > 350 && !recording) {
            Log.i("TAG", "2");
            recording = true;
        }

        if ((temp >= 0 && temp <= 350) && recording) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Save audio to file.");


            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");

            // Save audio to file.
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

            String name = tsLong.toString() + " "+  df.format(new Date());

            File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();

            fn = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV;

            logDB.insertData(name, fn);

            long totalAudioLen = 0;
            long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE;
            int channels = 2;
            long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE * channels / 8;
            totalAudioLen = totalReadBytes;
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
            byte finalBuffer[] = new byte[totalReadBytes + 44];

            finalBuffer[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
            finalBuffer[1] = 'I';
            finalBuffer[2] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[3] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[8] = 'W';
            finalBuffer[9] = 'A';
            finalBuffer[10] = 'V';
            finalBuffer[11] = 'E';
            finalBuffer[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[13] = 'm';
            finalBuffer[14] = 't';
            finalBuffer[15] = ' ';
            finalBuffer[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[17] = 0;
            finalBuffer[18] = 0;
            finalBuffer[19] = 0;
            finalBuffer[20] = 1;  // format = 1
            finalBuffer[21] = 0;
            finalBuffer[22] = (byte) channels;
            finalBuffer[23] = 0;
            finalBuffer[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
            finalBuffer[33] = 0;
            finalBuffer[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
            finalBuffer[35] = 0;
            finalBuffer[36] = 'd';
            finalBuffer[37] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[38] = 't';
            finalBuffer[39] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

            for (int i = 0; i < totalReadBytes; ++i)
                finalBuffer[44 + i] = totalByteBuffer[i];

            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(fn);
                try {
                    out.write(finalBuffer);
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //*/
            tempIndex++;
            totalReadBytes = 0;
            recording = false;

        }

        // -> Recording sound here.
        Log.i("TAG", "Recording Sound.");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadBytes; i++) {
            totalByteBuffer[totalReadBytes + i] = audioBuffer[i];
        }
        totalReadBytes += numberOfReadBytes;

        tempIndex++;

    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (recorder != null) {
        isRecording = false;

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if (i == 1)
            recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (isRecording) {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ListenFragment">

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/listen"
    android:textColor="#b1060e"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/listen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/listen"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `detectThread.start()` not `.run()`.  Start starts a new thread.  Run just calls the runnable on the current thread, which would be the UI thread making you unresponsive.